# In Apache Cassandra, is it possible to set the comparator and default validator using CQL 3.0?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Based on the Datastax webinar "[C*hristmas Comes Early – Creating your First Java Application with Apache Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/resources/webinars/collegecredit)", it looks like inserted columns that are not part of the schema default to a bytes datatype while column names are tied to String. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: As an addendum, column names are string unless used as components in the PRIMARY KEY expression, in which case they are the datatype defined for their value. Comparators with CQL3 are always CompositeType, with components of each PRIMARY KEY component after the first, and a UTF8 component appended. Thus, the CompositeType can be manipulated to have components of different datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bytes type is taken as the validator for cassandra-column-values.This cannot be changed for the inserted records.
In cassandra-cli use the following command to see the result in ascii

cli> assume  validator as ascii;

cli> list

Comment: This covers the default validator part of the question. I ended up answering my own question on the comparator - I misunderstood how comparators are defined in CQL3.